# Working out which BigQuery query I am paying for?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery and I have a question regarding billing - I have a recurring (almost daily) charge on my account and I think it is related to a query I have embedded into a published Tableau report - people are viewing the report and I am being charged - however the charge is more that I am expecting. How can I track the charge back to the specific query to confirm which one is raising the charge?

Thank you for your help,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by enabling audit logs and inspecting the logs.

Audit logs are available via Google Cloud Logging, where they can be immediately filtered to provide insights on specific jobs or queries, or exported to Google Cloud Pub/Sub, Google Cloud Storage, or BigQuery.

To analyze your aggregated BigQuery usage using SQL, set up export of audit logs back to BigQuery. For more information about setting up exports from Cloud Logging, see Overview of Logs Export in the [Cloud Logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2).

Analyzing Audit Logs Using BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have activated logs, but I wonder if there is a key identifier to track back to a query, rather then trying to match it by time stamps?

Comment: Try to do a LIKE statement and see how it goes. When you have `raw` data you need to identify your queries by exploring possibilities.